# Is this json wrong?

Tags: jquery, json, object

I've created the following json:

```
{ "posts" : [
    {"post" : 
        {"person" : somePerson,
        "messages" : [person says : Hello how are you,person2 says : I\'m fine]
        }
    },
    {"post" : 
        {"person" : someOtherPerson,
        "messages" : [person says : I\'m happy,person2 says : me too]
        }
    }
  ] 
}
```

But jquery .done is not being called with this input. I suspect there is something wrong with the format of the json. I don't know if I'm allowed to pass an array "messages" inside a json object. If I'm not, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Messages should be an object. And the keys and values must be quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://jsonlint.com/ or similar services:

```
Parse error on line 5:
...          "person": somePerson,        
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON format is wrong, let me show you how I counld do it:

```
{ "posts" : [
{
  "person": "Person1",
  "messages": [
    {
      "person": "Person1",
      "message": "I'm happy"
    },
    {
      "person": "Person2",
      "message": "me too"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "person": "Person3",
  "messages": [
    {
      "person": "Person3",
      "message": "Hello how are you"
    },
    {
      "person": "Person2",
      "message": "I'm fine"
    }
  ]
}
```

] 
}

*You have an array of `posts` right?, so why adding in it objects with the `"post"` attribute ?, it makes no sense, just make an object that defines the data of each post like I did

*In JSON, an array can't be an object like you wanted to do, arrays only contains objects or values like strings or numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces from property names. Change person says to person_says. And insert strings in quotes.

Comment: In that case "messages" must be changed to an object. Or he should use the messages without keys and send the entire item as value i.e. `["person 1 says : something","person 2 says : something"]`

Comment: Of course, "messages" must be array of objects: [{"person_1_says": "something"},{"person_2_says": "something"}] In the real project, object must have two field, name and message.